# VMWare Error: Cannot connect the virtual device sata0:1 because no corresponding device is available on the host

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, macos-highsierra

I am getting the following error: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqE9m.png)

My virtual disk is under my C: drive, while the configuration file was default created under My Documents>Virtual Machines.

I have no idea how to fix this problem as I am very new to virtualization. I followed this Youtube video to install Mac OS High Sierra: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szHn5GunojU